# Faster pandas DatetimeIndex membership checking

Tags: python, pandas, set, datetimeindex

I have a tight loop which, among other things, checks whether a given date (in the form of a `pandas.Timestamp`) is contained in a given **unique** `pandas.DatetimeIndex` (the application being checking whether a date is a custom business day).

As a minimal example, consider this bit:

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range("2020", "2021")
index = dates.to_series().sample(frac=0.7).sort_index().index

for date in dates:
    if date in index:
        # Do stuff...
```

(Note that simply iterating over `index` is not an option in the full application)

To my surprise, I found that the `date in index` bit takes up a significant part of the total runtime. Profiling furthermore shows that Pandas' membership check does a lot more than just a hash lookup, which is further confirmed by a small experiment comparing `DatetimeIndex` vs a plain python `set`:

```py
%timeit [date in index for date in dates]
# 3.28 ms ± 81.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

vs

```py
index_set = set(index)
%timeit [date in index_set for date in dates]
# 341 µs ± 3.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Note that the difference is almost 10x! Why this difference and can I do anything to make it faster?